# How to prevent an onchange redirect in a rails form using "onchange: '$(this.form).submit();"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is my code:

```
<div class="lists">
  <h1>Your Todo Lists</h1>
    <% @lists.each do |list| %>
      <div id="list">
        <%= list.title %>
        <% list.items.each do |item| %>
        <div class="item-list">
          <%= form_for :item, url: item_path(item), method: :post, html: { class: "item-box" } do |f|%>
            <%= f.label item.title %>
            <%= f.check_box item.id %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var changeDom = function(itemRow) {
      itemRow.closest(".item-list").remove()

      // $("complete-list").append(this)
    }

    var itemList = $(".item-list")
    itemList.find(":checkbox").on("change", function(box){
      var box = $(this)
      var item_number = parseInt(box[0].name.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g)[0])
      $.ajax( { type: "PUT",
          url: "items/" + item_number,
          data: { id: item_number },
          success: function(text) {
            changeDom(box[0].closest(".item-list"))
          }
        });
      })
    })
</script>
```

When I click a checkbox, it keeps me on the page and I hit the success callback in the ajax request. When I try doing this another way:

```
<h1>Things You Gotta Do</h1>
<% @lists.each do |list| %>
  <div id="list">
    <%= list.title %>
    <% list.items.each do |item| %>
      <%= form_for item do |f| %>
        <%= f.label item.title %>
        <%= f.check_box :status, onchange: '$(this.form).submit();' %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This way using the rails form **onchange**, it tries to redirect to another template ("/items/1") and I don't know why. How do I prevent that behavior? I want to stay on this page using this **onchange** because I want to manipulate the dom on that page.

Comment: Try adding remote: true to the form for. `<%= form_for item, remote: true do |item| %>`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your issue completely.

But your ajax example looks odd.

If you are using a standard Rails controller, there are usually two request types that are configured for most actions.   (if you are using the scaffolding tool to generate the controller).

Here is an example

```
  # PATCH/PUT /driver_procedures/1
  # PATCH/PUT /driver_procedures/1.json
  def update
    @driver_procedure.assign_attributes(driver_procedure_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @driver_procedure.save
        format.html { redirect_to @driver_procedure, notice: 'Driver procedure was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @driver_procedure }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @driver_procedure.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Notice that there is a HTML response and a JSON response.   Notice that the HTML version will redirect to a new page after is completes, but the JSON version doesn't - it just returns a JSON version of the model.

So if you're asking why does a standard form submit redirect to `/items/1` - because that's what a Rails controller will do by default after processing a form submission. You can see it in the code for the controller as above.

But if you're posting the data via ajax, you should make sure you are posting it to the correct route.   You want to post it to the JSON version of the route, by appending `.json` to the url.

```
    $.ajax( { type: "PUT",
      url: "items/" + item_number + '.json',
      data: { id: item_number },
      success: function(text) {

      }
    });
```

But otherwise, I'm not sure why you want to submit the form on the checkbox change. Your first approach using ajax made more sense I think.